# How to uninstall Java 9 using pacman (target not found)

Tags: java, arch-linux, pacman

I want to remove Java 9 and install Java 10, but I cannot remove it using pacman.

The result of `pacman -Q` (regarding Java 9):

```
java-environment-common 3-1
java-runtime-common 3-1
jdk9-openjdk 9.0.4.u11-1
jre9-openjdk 9.0.4.u11-1
jre9-openjdk-headless 9.0.4.u11-1
```

But when I use `sudo pacman -Rsc`, it says `target not found`. Can you help me?

Comment: What argument are you giving `pacman -Rsc`? The results of `pacman -Q` tell you the package names to use.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a Java version entirely, do this:

```
sudo pacman -R jre9-openjdk jdk9-openjdk jre9-openjdk-headless && sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk
```

Then you can install the newer JDK with

```
sudo pacman -S jdk10-openjdk
```

You can see installed Java versions using

```
archlinux-java status
```